# There is no email received

Tags: java, sql-server, email, smtp, registration

I successfully send the email, there is no error but I did not received any email in my inbox.
why is this happening?

```
public static void main(String [] args){ 

  String to = "abc@yahoo.com";
  String from = "def@gmail.com";
  String host = "localhost";

 //Get the session object  
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);  
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  

 //compose the message  
  try{  
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
     message.setSubject("Ping");  
     message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");  

     // Send message  
     Transport.send(message);  
     System.out.println("message sent successfully....");  

  }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}  
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: Yahoo probably considers an email like this to be spam so please check your spam folder. Reasons for that: the subject is suspicious, you're most probably not sending from your gmail account (assuming it's yours) and the content is too short.

Comment: Are you sure you have an SMTP server running in your local?

Comment: @Thomas Thank you sir. it was stored in the SPAM.

Comment: Btw sir, Is it possible that we can directly send it in the inbox? I send it in different address(not yahoo) but the same thing happened. It was stored in SPAM too...

Comment: I'm not an expert on spam detection but since email providers can use a different set of rules it's hard to tell. There are a few general rules though: 1) avoid short/suspicous subjects such as "Ping", 2) avoid cryptic messages or ones with many links and little text, 3) try to send via the mail server(s) registered for the sender address you want to use (gmail in your case) - many spam filters will check where the email comes from and if the origin doesn't match the servers indicated by the sender address that email will be considered spam (hint: have a look "spf records").

Answer (score 0):

Found out the source of the problem. The letter went to spam section. My E-mail from field says that it was sent from def@gmail.com, but I am not using Gmail SMTP and same address to send this E-mail. It's like I am using a fake identity to send the e-mail. So my incoming mail server which is pss.com.ph thinks it is a spam mail.